# Adding a tag to existing Note?

Tags: php, evernote

I'm trying to update a note(s) that are returned from an Evernote search using PHP. The search part works just fine, but once I find the list of notes I can't seem to add a tag to the note. I can confirm that tag GUIDs are correct in both cases.

```
    use EDAM\NoteStore\NoteFilter;
$client = new Client(array(
 'token' => $authToken,
 'sandbox' => true
));
$filter = new NoteFilter();

$filter->words = "HIGH";
$filter->tagGuids =  array("ababe33d-75e6-4a50-b2ba-61889bb2b8a6");
$notes_result = $client->getNoteStore()->findNotes($filter, 0, 10);
$notes = $notes_result->notes;
foreach ($notes as $note) {
    echo $note->title . "\n";
    // **** ERROR HERE ****
    $note->updateTag($authToken, "b3b290fa-4ca0-493e-8dd1-5cf1bff28b92");
}
```

Comment: When you have "ERROR HERE", is there an error thrown?

Comment: Error: Call to undefined method EDAM\Types\Note::updateTag() in /var/www/html/en_test/sample/client/rules_engine.php:94
Stack trace:
#0 {main}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because `updateTag` must be called on NoteStore, not the note object. But: [NoteStore.updateTag](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_updateTag) updates the *tag object itself*. To add tag to a note one needs [NoteStore.updateNote](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_updateNote) instead. Your API token must also support write permission on notes.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I'll try that and get back on this. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: https://github.com/ryanddunn/en_tasklist for anyone interested in PHP & Evernote API, this the repo and code base associated with this question.